# Spring Cloud Config Server with Kerberized git uri

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I have Project in which we are trying to implement spring Cloud Config Server.

In this i am trying to use a git uri but there is a Kerberos authentication on the git uri.

How should i add required Kerberos token as header  to the git uri?

In short i want to add a custom rest template when cloud config server tries to access the git uri.

The property `spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri` is in `application.properties`